# In java library "jaunt", how to click a button which is not of type="submit"?

Tags: java, web-scraping, screen-scraping, jaunt-api

I am doing a web scraping using jaunt java library. I find code to submit a "submit" button in the examples and the tutorials available.
But how to click a normal button  which is not of type "submit"?

Ref:http://jaunt-api.com/

Answer (score -2):

```
form.submit("button label");
```

check this out
http://jaunt-api.com/examples/Example15.java

Comment: actually this doesn't work when there is no button value defined